# I can't access JSON with JavaScript from FireBase

Tags: javascript, json

I starting to use JSON , I got this problem

```
{
  "Usuarios" : {
    "1_Michelle" : {
      "datos" : {
        "afeccion" : "72",
        "lat" : "-0.2830356023921064",
        "lng" : "-78.55023108422756",
      }
    },
    "2_Javier" : {
      "datos" : {
        "afeccion" : "72",
        "lat" : "-0.2830356023921064",
        "lng" : "-78.55023108422756",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to save like this

```
var users=["1_Michelle","2_Javier"];
var lat = [123n,123n];
var lng = [123n,123n];
```

but The main problem that I got it's I can't access for the second entity  that are Michelle and Javier , I was trying for each but it doesn't work idk why.
This JSON I'm getting from FireBase 
Any help would be really appreciated and good rated ty

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the non-working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that JSON you have in `data` variable, then you can get these names with this

```
let names = Object.keys(data.Usuarios)
```

Then you will have these names in `names`

Comment: Thanks my friend I don't even know that there is a way to access via object keys. I'm really thanked you to you.
Sorry if this seems an easy question for you , but for me who is starting at this point using json was really hard, thanks for all

Comment: We're here to help :) Have a nice day

Comment: @MiguelAngelEsparzaCalero See [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/4642212).